# Counting the records of two columns from different tables

Tags: sql-server, join, count, multiple-columns

So I have this:

```
select count(InvoiceUniqueness) as [Nbr], CONVERT(varchar(12), ProcessDate, 101) as [Date]
from PreProcessTransLog
where (CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 102)) >= dateadd (m,-24,getdate()) and CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 120) <= GETDATE() 
and InitialStatus =2
group by CONVERT(varchar(12), ProcessDate, 101)
order by CAST (CONVERT(varchar(12), ProcessDate, 101) as smalldatetime) desc
```

I want to count the records under the InvoiceUniqueness column from the PreProcessTransLog table and count the records under (column not in the code) ManualBillHeaderID from another table called Ex_Manual_Bill_Header. I want to display both count results in a new column called Nbr. So in simpler terms, lets say I count column1 from T1 and column2 from T2. column1 has 10 records and column2 has 5. I want to join both columns into one so I can display 15 records. Keep in mind the columns have different names. hope im explaining myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) AS [Date],
    ISNULL(t1.Nbr, 0), + ISNULL(t2.Nbr, 0) AS Total
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(InvoiceUniqueness) AS [Nbr], CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ProcessDate, 101) AS [Date]
        FROM PreProcessTransLog
        WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 102))>=DATEADD(m, -24, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 120)<=GETDATE() AND InitialStatus=2
        GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ProcessDate, 101)
        --ORDER BY [Date]
    ) t1,
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(ManualBillHeaderID ) AS [Nbr], CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ProcessDate, 101) AS [Date]
        FROM <whatever table>
        WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 102))>=DATEADD(m, -24, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, ProcessDate, 120)<=GETDATE() AND InitialStatus=2
        GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ProcessDate, 101)
        --ORDER BY [Date]
    ) t2 ON t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date])
```

Comment: do you mind explaining what do I have to add to the logic you gave me.  I added the table on <whatever table> but is there anything else I need to change. The Date right?

Comment: You'll need to update the query to follow your table's schema.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your request accurately, I would do something like this.

Do your counts, off each table, and merge the results with a `UNION ALL`, wrap that up in a sub-query, and `SUM()` the resulting counts.

```
declare @table1 table (id int identity(1,1), recorddate datetime)
declare @table2 table (id int identity(1,1), otherdate datetime)

insert into @table1 
select '2014-08-01' union all
select '2014-08-01'


insert into @table2
select '2014-08-01' union all
select '2014-08-02'

select SUM(num), recorddate
from (select COUNT(1) num, recorddate
        from @table1
        group by recorddate

        union all

        select COUNT(1) num, otherdate 
        from @table2
        group by otherdate ) x
group by recorddate
```

In the case you want the results separate, change the last query to this:

```
select COUNT(*) num, recorddate
from @table1
group by recorddate
union all
select COUNT(*) num, otherdate 
from @table2
group by otherdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UNION ALL.  For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(Column1) AS [Nbr]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ColumnToGroupOn1

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(Column2)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY ColumnToGroupOn2
```

Or if you want to include the date column/s:

```
SELECT COUNT(Column1) AS [Nbr], ColumnToGroupOn1 AS [Date]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ColumnToGroupOn1

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(Column2), ColumnToGroupOn2
FROM Table2
GROUP BY ColumnToGroupOn2
```